# Wheel for 15mm x 110mm QR thru axle

Tags: quick-release, through-axle

I have a 2017 Genesis Datum 10 gravel bike.  I'm looking to get an extra set of wheels fitted with road tyres, to allow easy swapping between "gravel" and "road" modes.

The front fork has a 15mm QR thru axle (pictured).  Road wheels for 15mm QR axles are now less common but still possible to find - for example, this [Scribe Race-D wheelset](https://scribecycling.co.uk/products/raced-alloy-wheelset).

However, road wheel axles nowadays seem to have standard O.L.D. lengths (i.e. between the insides of the fork, excluding the threads) of 100mm, and hence hubs are made to fit this width.

My thru axle has a corresponding length of approximately 112mm (the total length including threads is 125mm, which is printed on the axle).

Is it possible to use a wheel with a hub made for a 100mm axle on my 112mm axle?  If not, what are my options for upgrading the wheelset?

[image]

Comment: Can you get another wheelset that is identical to your gravel set-up and mount road tires on that?

Comment: @user2705196 In theory yes (if they still make them 5 years later) but I thought I might as well get a lighter/faster set for the road tyres.

Comment: It's a good thought. Just keep in mind that swapping wheels can be annoyingly fiddly if the discs aren't *exactly* in the same position. Thus one thing to consider is using the same hubs and discs as on your gravel wheels. Then you can use a 'fancy' rim if you want and might get away without having to readjust the brake calipers with each wheel swap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thru axles vary in their dimensions. Remember they are unique to each frame, and the dropouts vary in thickness. When matching a wheel, what matters is the over locknut diameter of the hub and the axle size. As you are talking about a 2017 drop bar bike, this is very likely to be 100mm OLD. You may want to verify the thru axle diameter as well, as 15mm is typically associated with MTBs (but there are some exceptions, probably more so from the 2016-2018 period).

A 110mm OLD is associated with the Boost standard for MTBs, which very few gravel bikes follow. MTBs need the additional wheel strength, but few gravel bikes do - if you needed that type of strength, you may be on the wrong type of bicycle.

Comment: You're right - I double checked the frame (as opposed to the axle) and the OLD is indeed 100mm.  Thanks!